# Label Images in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Given the same binary input image (up to inversion), is there a guarantee that the labels in the images returned by all the following functions are all consistent?

- [`cv::distanceTransform()` (version with labels)](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga8a0b7fdfcb7a13dde018988ba3a43042)
- [`cv::connectedComponents()`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gac2718a64ade63475425558aa669a943a)
- [`cv::connectedComponentsWithStats()`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gae57b028a2b2ca327227c2399a9d53241)

Does this appear in the docs anywhere?

Comment: Because it would save the trouble of mapping from one label set to another when needing to access the Voronoi vs. the actual blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass to `distanceTransform` a binary image **inverted** with respect to `connectedComponents` or `connectedComponentsWithStats`, the labels are computed the same way and **will be consistent**.

I was not able to find any reference in the doc, but the labels will be computed by the same algorithm (`connectedComponents_sub1`) in all cases.

**connectedComponents[WithStats]**

```
int cv::connectedComponents(InputArray _img, OutputArray _labels, int connectivity, int ltype){
    const cv::Mat img = _img.getMat();
    _labels.create(img.size(), CV_MAT_DEPTH(ltype));
    cv::Mat labels = _labels.getMat();
    connectedcomponents::NoOp sop;
    if(ltype == CV_16U){
        return connectedComponents_sub1(img, labels, connectivity, sop);
    }else if(ltype == CV_32S){
        return connectedComponents_sub1(img, labels, connectivity, sop);
    }else{
        CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "the type of labels must be 16u or 32s");
        return 0;
    }
}


int cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(InputArray _img, OutputArray _labels, OutputArray statsv,
                                     OutputArray centroids, int connectivity, int ltype)
{
    const cv::Mat img = _img.getMat();
    _labels.create(img.size(), CV_MAT_DEPTH(ltype));
    cv::Mat labels = _labels.getMat();
    connectedcomponents::CCStatsOp sop(statsv, centroids);
    if(ltype == CV_16U){
        return connectedComponents_sub1(img, labels, connectivity, sop);
    }else if(ltype == CV_32S){
        return connectedComponents_sub1(img, labels, connectivity, sop);
    }else{
        CV_Error(CV_StsUnsupportedFormat, "the type of labels must be 16u or 32s");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the labeling part is performed by the `connectedComponents_sub1` function in both cases. The only difference between the two is the statistic computation: `connectedcomponents::NoOp` versus `connectedcomponents::CCStatsOp`, not relevant for label computation.

**distanceTransform**

```
void cv::distanceTransform( InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst, OutputArray _labels,
                        int distType, int maskSize, int labelType )
{
    ...
    if( labelType == CV_DIST_LABEL_CCOMP )
    {
        Mat zpix = src == 0;
        connectedComponents(zpix, labels, 8, CV_32S);
    }
    ...
}
```

The labels are computed internally by the function `connectedComponents`.

Comment: Good catch on the inversion. I forgot to mention that :-).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and research. If this is not "incidental", maybe it should be added to the docs. I'll open an issue about it.